# Migrating TFS hosted on azure to on-premise

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cb80f0d-0119-4277-82e8-719a8db1796e

This is the link which was shared in a similar post some two years ago. However the link is not available anymore. Do we have an alternative.

Comment: When you say "TFS hosted on Azure" are you talking about Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to migrate from VSTS to TFS on-premise, please see [Migrate VSO to on premises TFS](http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/move-vso-premises-tfs/).

You can also have a try for [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration),it allows you to bulk edit and migrate data between Team Projects on both Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

Then the alternative way would be get and upload the source code manually. And [use Execl to export and import the work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel).

Also, you can use [OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility](http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/), the Commercial Edition supports migration from either TFS or VSTS to either TFS or VSTS.

Comment: @Preeti Any update for this? is that helpful for you?

Comment: Hey Andy, I haven't got the chance to carry out these options yet. Once, I am through it I'll surely update it here.

Comment: Hi Andy- No. We plan to take up a backup from azure and then restore it. That's all  we have as of now. We plan to first run this up on a test environment and see how much successful we are.